# How to show that the span of vectors is a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry, affine-varieties

I am studying the course of affine and Euclidean goemetry. I am new to this course. I have studied two theorems of the affine combination.

1. The point $y$ is an affine combination of points $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3},...,v_{k}$ $iff$ $y-v_{1}$ is a linear combination of the points $v_{2}-v_{1}, v_{3}-v_{1}, ..., v_{k}-v_{1}.$
2. $y$ comes from affine combination of the points $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3},...,v_{k}$ $iff$ homogenuous form of $y$ comes in the linear combination of homogenuous form of vectors $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3},...,v_{k}.$

Now the question is if {${v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}}$} is basis for $R^{3}$, then how can I show that Span{${v_{2}-v_{1}, v_{3}-v_{1}}$} is plane in $R^{3}$ and Aff{${v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}}$} is plane through $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}$.
I don't know how to utilize these theorems to handle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Any 2-dimensional subspace is a plane. So if you show that v$_2$-v$_1$ and v$_3$-v$_1$ are linearly independent, then you'd be done.

I'm confused what Aff{$v_2-v_1,v_3-v_1$} is. Do you mean the affine hull? Because the affine hull of 2 points is the line segment connecting the 2.

Comment: Sir but how can I show in general that if $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}$ are basis for $R^{3}$ then $v_{2}-v_{1}$ and $v_{3}-v_{1}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Suppose not. Let $c_1(v_2-v_1)+c_2(v_3-v_1)$ = 0 for some constants $c_1,c_2$. Can anything be said about $v_1,v_2,v_3$?

Comment: Thanks u so much
Aff{$v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}$} means affine hull
Can you explain this part of the question that it represent the plane passing through the $v_{1}, v_{2} and v_{3}$.

Comment: From your first theorem, y $\in$ Aff$\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ iff $y-v_1$ is in Span$\{v_2-v_1,v_3-v_1\}$, which we have proven is a plane. Now you want to show that $v_1,v_2,v_3 \in$ Aff$\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$